# Why is inversion used in "And boy, have we patented it!"?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, exclamations

In 2007, Steve Jobs announced the first iPhone. During the presentation, he introduced a feature called Multi-touch; he said,

> "And boy, have we patented it!"

What I am wondering about is the reason why the subject "we", and the auxiliary "have" are inverted here. It doesn't seem to be an interrogative sentence to me, or is it a rhetorical question, by any chance? I have no idea of it. I would really appreciate it if you answer my question.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not equipped to provide any kind of syntactical analysis. But in case it helps, this kind of inversion is quite common, and it simply lends emphasis. It’s a kind of intensifier. The canonical set phrase of this type is “Have we ever!” or “Did they ever!”, used as a response to a yes/no question. “Did the Giant win last night?” “Boy, did they *ever*!” (emphatically yes: they kicked butt).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That's interesting. Then is this kind of inversion never understood as a question?

Comment: It can. For example “Can you believe he accused us of short changing him?” “Unbelievable. Have we *ever*?”. Though in that case the question is rhetorical, but you get the idea. You can use it for legit questions too. “Are we going to harvest the crops in August this year?” “Have we ever?”. These kinds of examples can be distinguished from the emphatic statement kind Jobs used because they end with question marks and the Jobs-like ones don’t.

Comment: Oh, then this is a totally different kind of inversion from those common ones like question inversion and negative inversion, etc. Never thought there’s something else. Thanks, Dan Bron. Your comment is really helpful.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I am glad my comments were helpful to you. But as I said, I’m not equipped to give you a proper analysis of the syntax underlying it. I’m hoping you get proper answers or comments from our resident experts, like Prof. Lawler, Prof Shor, BillJ, sumelic, Arucaria, StoneyB, or any of the several others. They *know* their stuff. I’m looking forward to learning the answer as much as you are. Good question, thanks for asking.

Comment: Hope we can get a more detailed explanation of this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construction is known as an exclamatory inversion, [common in German, Dutch, and English](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6135/4c2b5d3fcdf2d81090c1bc34a50887415156.pdf?_ga=2.237605507.28118357.1542197819-728540877.1542197819), less so among Scandinavian languages. As in your example, it is often preceded by an interjection:

> And, oh man, [*was I ever going to have a talk*](https://books.google.de/books?id=pb3SAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&dq=%22man,+was+I+ever%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1q6Kd-dPeAhWILlAKHZtoAQ0Q6AEIPTAE) with probable arsonist Mr. Rouse the Louse, whether my detective liked it or not. — Maggie Shayne, *Deadly Obsession*, 2014, 38.
>
> For many years, lots of purse-lipped parents, uptight teachers, and pontificating pundits frowned upon computers because they saw them as noninteractive machines that only served to encourage anti-social behavior. [*Boy, did they ever get that wrong!*](https://books.google.de/books?id=xP6V2jyaSpMC&pg=PA219&dq=%22boy,+did+they+ever%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim_qeP_NPeAhXPDewKHSETDf84ChDoATABegQIARAJ) — Paul McFedries, *The Complete Idiot's Guide to Microsoft Windows XP*, 2001, 219.
>
> Dave Mustaine is famed for going out and finding the best players he can when Megadeth’s lineup goes into flux, and [*damn did he ever deliver this week.*](https://www.metalinsider.net/columns/metal-power-rankings-a-big-4-band-names-their-2) 3 Apr. 2015, Metal Insider.

Whether such clauses are truly exclamatory or, following [Huddleston](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002438419390025R),  “[represent a type of interrogative/question that can be used with the indirect illocutionary force of an exclamatory statement](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00437956.2005.11432550)” is the object of scholarly debate.